# In the Twitter REST API, is it possible to find the reply count?

Tags: api, twitter

In the Twitter REST API, is it possible to find the reply count? I see retweet_count and favorite_count. However, I'd like to get the reply count, which you can see in any of the GUIs next to the text bubble icon (see below on the left).

As far as I can tell, there's no direct way to get this data point; one would have to do two or more api hits to collect that count. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The twitter API doesn't provide a field for reply count but there are work arounds which can help.
But there are few points which are very tricky as each reply even by the same person is counted (much like a dialogue) handling that to count it once is a tricky task. 
you can find further details [here](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-get-a-count-of-the-replies-and-retweets-for-a-particular-tweet)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics

```
data.public_metrics.reply_count
```

A count of how many times the Tweet has been replied to.

Using the public_metrics field, this will return the total count of replies from both organic and paid contexts, in order to maintain consistency with the counts shown publicly on Twitter.

```
data.organic_metrics.reply_count
```

Using the organic_metrics field, this returns the total count of replies from organic contexts.

```
data.promoted_metrics.reply_count
```

Using the promoted_metrics field, this returns the total count of replies from paid contexts.